# docker build --platform=linux/amd64 fails: ERROR: failed to solve: no match for platform in manifest

Tags: docker, buildx

On a Macbook M2 machine I am getting an error when creating a docker build.

This is the most boiled down example that can reproduce the error:

```
echo "FROM alpine:latest" | docker build --platform=linux/amd64 --progress=plain -f - .
```

### error message

Notice the error in the last line:

```
#5 ERROR: no match for platform in manifest sha256:d9ab3e9e8a65da61fb54c3e2471c8fabf787ce49403919bff7eaf10f99e33215: not found
------
 > exporting to image:
------
ERROR: failed to solve: no match for platform in manifest sha256:d9ab3e9e8a65da61fb54c3e2471c8fabf787ce49403919bff7eaf10f99e33215: not found
```

### Full error output:

```
#1 [internal] load .dockerignore
#1 transferring context: 2B done
#1 DONE 0.0s

#2 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
#2 transferring dockerfile: 93B done
#2 DONE 0.0s

#3 [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/alpine:latest
#3 DONE 0.6s

#4 [1/1] FROM docker.io/library/alpine:latest@sha256:02bb6f428431fbc2809c5d1b41eab5a68350194fb508869a33cb1af4444c9b11
#4 resolve docker.io/library/alpine:latest@sha256:02bb6f428431fbc2809c5d1b41eab5a68350194fb508869a33cb1af4444c9b11 0.0s done
#4 CACHED

#5 exporting to image
#5 exporting layers done
#5 exporting manifest sha256:c887664786a565506760c1ebb17d0edbbc0f8427a4e723d05bba6dc1c199f63f done
#5 exporting config sha256:c9eabdf343eb2fef6b265aa86db47ee270dd0a170bf37bef1dcf94fa73236b65 done
#5 exporting attestation manifest sha256:ff813dfd9ec5f193d95d20bafa96b3d48b7510d178d4ef3195981314151856f1 done
#5 exporting manifest list sha256:d9ab3e9e8a65da61fb54c3e2471c8fabf787ce49403919bff7eaf10f99e33215 done
#5 naming to moby-dangling@sha256:d9ab3e9e8a65da61fb54c3e2471c8fabf787ce49403919bff7eaf10f99e33215 done
#5 unpacking to moby-dangling@sha256:d9ab3e9e8a65da61fb54c3e2471c8fabf787ce49403919bff7eaf10f99e33215 done
#5 ERROR: no match for platform in manifest sha256:d9ab3e9e8a65da61fb54c3e2471c8fabf787ce49403919bff7eaf10f99e33215: not found
------
 > exporting to image:
------
ERROR: failed to solve: no match for platform in manifest sha256:d9ab3e9e8a65da61fb54c3e2471c8fabf787ce49403919bff7eaf10f99e33215: not found
```

However, I can run any of the images easily if I do either:

```
$ docker run --rm -ti --platform linux/amd64 alpine:latest uname -a
Linux b2a7299eadea 5.15.49-linuxkit #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Sep 13 07:51:32 UTC 2022 x86_64 Linux
$ docker run --rm -ti --platform linux/arm64 alpine:latest uname -a
Linux 00ecc31c7eeb 5.15.49-linuxkit #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Sep 13 07:51:32 UTC 2022 aarch64 Linux
```

so there is a problem if I want to **build an image**, but no problem if I try to run it.

### Troubleshooting:

1. My machine is ARM-based apple M2 processor:

```
$ uname -a
Darwin 22.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 22.5.0: Mon Apr 24 20:53:19 PDT 2023; root:xnu-8796.121.2~5/RELEASE_ARM64_T6020 arm64
```

2. I know that rosetta qemu emulation works, because I can run

```
$ docker run --rm -ti --platform linux/amd64 alpine:latest uname -m
x86_64
```

3. docker builder is correctly configured for multiplatform builds:

```
$ docker builder ls
NAME/NODE       DRIVER/ENDPOINT STATUS  BUILDKIT PLATFORMS
default *       docker                           
  default       default         running v0.11.6  linux/arm64, linux/riscv64, linux/ppc64le, linux/s390x, linux/386, linux/mips64le, linux/mips64
desktop-linux   docker                           
  desktop-linux desktop-linux   running v0.11.6  linux/arm64, linux/riscv64, linux/ppc64le, linux/s390x, linux/386, linux/mips64le, linux/mips64
```

### question:

so the question is: How can I use `docker build` and actually save a docker image locally?

Comment: Are you using Docker Desktop? Which version?

Comment: I am using docker desktop 4.19.0 (most recent as of writing)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your error should be related to this open issue https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/44578 that enter into Docker Desktop 4.20.

As a workaround, you should disable the flag `Use containerd for pulling and storing images` within the feature of Docker Desktop to solve it.

You find the setting `Use containerd for pulling and storing images` in Docker Desktop, "Settings" > "Features in development"

Comment: Disabling the setting mentioned, worked and solved my problem. Thanks @Alez.

Comment: This still seems to be an issue in 4.20.1.

Comment: Seems to be properly fixed in BuildKit [v0.12.0](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/releases/tag/v0.12.0).

_When exporting an image to Containerd image store, unpack logic now works for multi-platform images by unpacking only the native platform by default #3982 #3983_

Not yet landed in moby: https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/45966

Answer (score 1):

Another possible cause for this error could be an invalid platform string. Sending an invalid platform string will prevent docker from parsing the correct tag, i.e. `--platform=linux/amd` will fail, whereas `--platform=linux/amd64` succeeds.